# English as a computer language : research links needed

Tags: grammar, synonyms, computing, research

I conducted a small experiment some time back.

The idea originated during e-mail composition when I wanted to examine the possibility of conveying something more than what is typically expressed in everyday vocabulary in given contexts. So I had the idea of finding a common synonyms list for what I wanted to say and what is generally said, then select the best one, which satisfies both, if possible.

Wrote a bash script in Linux by taking a word and keeping the synonyms in a queue (appending to master synonyms file for the word). Like in BFS(tree) algorithm, take next element, generate synonyms, insert at the end of queue. As the distance increases, relevancy may come down.

During the testing, I had on occasion even taken 2 words which are antonyms and found a harmony !!

- motility, immotility : fermentation
- true, false : creation
- ink, vomit: pen

(Used Princeton university’s mysql database transformed English dictionary)

There are times I did not get any common word. So they are orthogonal.

When I find these minute discoveries matching with known things (even for creation - there is already a nasadeeya sukta in Indian philosophy. I guess similar ones should be there in philosophies originated at different places as well) and when I see this embedded in the language, thinking, may be yet unknown might have been handled.

With sanskrit, I know of at least one research at a very very early stage (I am one of the authors) given below (redirects to google drive stored document), the contents of which are not definitely yet in a polished form, but sharing it here as I guess most of the people who are in research at least will take the relevant and positive parts for the context needed:

https://tiny.cc/sanskrit_latest

(tiny link for https://drive.google.com/file/d/18wVYPdmEqWVcfzNWlRLle2YIxslRbL1J )

So in the similar lines, may be a subset words and grammar of English with very few new additions if required, can itself be used as a Domain Specific Language (DSL) for many domains?

Potential for long lasting success if we can get a proper DLS out of English is more. In a given DSL's aimed domain, may be we can to some extent figure out these kind of relations or in the proposed language, can verify with some tests of this kind and take a subset of English with its words and grammar and make it a DSL. For example. A bagel can mean a lot depending on the power of DSL. A cooking DSL or scientific DSL or a super GDSL, which can handle all. I see no possibility not to achieve with current technology at least part of this to start with.

Was there any research in this direction? Any pointers to study further?

Please note, some of this content may not be presented in an acceptable form, satisfying for everyone. If so, it is definitely not by any intention but to share as is while editing to the extent that I can think of and modify when sharing in a global platform. Request to go ahead and edit the post if you see it can be bettered for everyone.

edit: appending the following line:
There are in fact even more things rather minute discoveries like the shape of the letter and transformations on it yielding very interesting results, semantics wise wrt computer applications. Was there any research in all these kind of stuff?

edit 2: yet another append:
by very interesting, it was about suddenly expanded similarities with sanskrit semantics and syntax wise (even sounding) and finding some of its characteristics when these transformations are made.

edit 3: appending:
Found a better answer from comments and highlighting here by mentioning it:

[Attempto_Controlled_English](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Attempto_Controlled_English&oldid=948780945)

Comment: Could you state more clearly what your question is? Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for english being used as a DSL and also for a potential language in computers in the lines discussed above because it can be a commercial success. I am looking for existing research.

Comment: Attempts at using "natural" English (and no doubt Russian, and several other languages) to form a computer language have been made many times.  COBOL is probably the most notable.

Comment: Where’s the harmony in vomit and pen? How are they synonyms and how would substituting one for another lead to expressing more than is typical for the context?

Comment: The closest I ever saw was HyperTalk. It had pronouns and articles, prepositions, and a lot more. But it was still not English.

Comment: @Jim, I agree vomit and pen was not a good one to mention here. But I do see it did indeed satisfy finding a common meaning when 2 words are given. I am not sure why is not an example.

Comment: @Hot Licks, COBOL is not a DSL though some claim. At that time it could have been the best effort by probably anyone. Now that we have more clarity, as a learning I think we need to put more effort on the delineation parts in the design and the strict definition of DSL

Comment: @John Lawler, thanks. Did not know HyperTalk. Just looked at wikipedia article. It is not proper for me to immediately comment without giving proper thought and noting positives in it. Will do it.

Comment: @Hot Licks, Is there any standard research which can be pointed in this direction. It is quite possible languages like Russian also has hidden potential. I am comfortable with English, the language in which I have read many books and through which I have got lot of knowledge. So it is natural for me to consider English when doing any analysis on transformations like replacing 'w' with 'm', 'k' with 'c' (to share few simple ones) and make some sense which is inclusive and map similarities, exacts or reverse map to explain and connect vast data points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_programming

Comment: @Hot Licks, great resource. Heard NLP but never expanded the acronym/thought my research comes under the same. I think this can be taken as answer.

Comment: Do some reading on IBM Watson. Speech recognition is a very old area of research, and its latest accomplishments are impressive.

Comment: @Global Charm, yes. Know about IBM Watson. But not done extensive study.

Comment: See [Attempto Controlled English](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Attempto_Controlled_English&oldid=948780945) and follow the links from that article.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Much better answer. I can fuse these concepts there in a better way.

Comment: Please note that 'There are times I did not get any common word. So they are orthogonal.' assumes that (b) your research technique is inerrant (quite possibly true) but (a) that your synonym-generator is inerrant. Since 'synonymity' is an ill-defined concept (not all accomplished Anglophone linguists would agree on all 'synonym-sets'), and polysemy is at least as difficult to apply a precising definition to, 'orthogonal' itself as used here must be 'according to our terminology'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an approximation of "normal" spoken/written language to program a computer is known as [Natural Language Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_programming):

> Natural-language programming (NLP) is an ontology-assisted way of
>   programming in terms of natural-language sentences, e.g. English. A
>   structured document with Content, sections and subsections for
>   explanations of sentences forms a NLP document, which is actually a
>   computer program. Natural languages and natural-language user
>   interfaces include Inform7, a natural programming language for making
>   interactive fiction, Ring, a general-purpose language, Shakespeare, an
>   esoteric natural programming language in the style of the plays of
>   William Shakespeare, and Wolfram Alpha, a computational knowledge
>   engine, using natural-language input. Some methods for program
>   synthesis are based on natural-language programming.

Comment: I will note that if you have any further questions about this you should probably ask them on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Sure. I had actually got a thought after posting: probably http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/ would have been a better one to ask for guidance before posting here.